# TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function phonegap jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, typeerror

I have an issue with phonegap. It is very weird issue and I cannot catch it everytime.
I write an iphone app using phonegap 2.2 and jquery mobile 1.0.
In fact my code works correct in browser (test in chrome and safari and never have such error), but when I use app I often have TypeError:

For example I try to call js function

```
Pages['thread'].beforeShow();
```

In file Thread.js I have something like this:

```
Pages['thread'] = {
    ...
    beforeShow: function() {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

and sometimes, especially when I run app from background I have error

- TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function
- file: .../Thread.js
- line: 19 (the line of "beforeShow")

So how it can be possible? It knows the file where the function is situated, it knows what line function is on, but throws TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function.

I have no idea :( Maybe someone has?

Thanks!

Comment: `line: 19 (the line of "beforeShow")` then you should show us line 19 ;).

Comment: 18:
19: beforeShow: function() {
20:     
21:     alert('here');

Comment: Any chance of beforeShow property getting overwritten? May be you catch this error and then try logging the property.

Comment: thx:) already working on it, but it happens very seldom and if I make any changes I can't be sure that it is the fix :(